# Django - get id of posted form in post method of view that contains list of forms

Tags: python, html, django

I have a view that display a list of Lecture object each lecture has a file select button that automatically submits the selected file.

The relevant part in html template:

```
{% for lecture in past_lectures %}
    <form method = "post" id=upload_{{lecture.pk}} action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" onchange="$('#upload_{{lecture.pk}}').submit();" value="Upload Audio..."/>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

The view class:

```
class LectureListView(ListView):
    model = Lecture
    ordering = ('name', )
    context_object_name = 'past_lectures'
    template_name = 'professor/home.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        professor = self.request.user.professor
        lecture_queryset = Lecture.objects.filter(course__professor = professor)

        return lecture_queryset

    def post(self, request,):
        pk = int(request.POST['id'].split('_').[-1]) #return the pk portion of the id of the form
        lecture = Lecture.objects.get(pk=pk)
        lecture.audio = request.FILES['audio'] #audio is the name of the filefield in Lecture model
        lecture.save()
        return reverse('professor:home')
```

The problem is that request.POST['id'] does not return the id of the form but rather looks for any element with the name 'id' which doesn't exist.

How do I get the lecture.pk value based on the form submitted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have the `pk` of the object you can send it via an `hidden input`

```
<input type='hidden' value='{{lecture.pk}}' name='pk'>
```

by the way, you will never get the audio with the key `audio`, since that name does not exist in your form, you should provide the name in the `input file`

```
<input type="file" name='audio' onchange="$('#upload_{{lecture.pk}}').submit();" value="Upload Audio..."/>
```

Since your form is to send files, you miss to provide the header with `enctype='multipart/form-data'`, so your whole form would be like the following:

```
{% for lecture in past_lectures %}
<form method = "post" id=upload_{{lecture.pk}} action=""  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' value='{{lecture.pk}}' name='id'>
    <input type="file" name='audio' onchange="$('#upload_{{lecture.pk}}').submit();" value="Upload Audio..."/>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Data available for your view:

```
pk = request.POST.get('id')
audio = request.FILES.get('audio')
```

Comment: I am new to Django so this is immensely helpful! Thank you.